# laravel php array grouping using anather array value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, laravel-livewire

I have a problem with array group. Could you please help me to solve this problem. I want to group acording to the **$group** array value. For a Example, first Group 01 items & second Group 02 items in the table.

```
// In Controller
 public $inputs = [0, 1, 2];
 public $item_id = [18, 19, 20], $group = ['Group 01', 'Group 02', 'Group 01'];

//In blead
<tbody class="text-xs divide-y divide-gray-100 ">
  @forelse ($inputs  as $key => $value)
   <tr> 
     <td class="p-2"> 
      {{ $group[$value] }} 
     </td>

     <td class="p-2"> 
     {{ $item_id[$value] }} 
     </td>
   </tr>
  @empty
  @endforelse
```

If Can I want give group name each group strat before first item like topic. Thank you

**Edit 01**

I am making a Laravel livewire application. In my application, I am adding dynamic inputs and I want to show it my blead view.

[image]

As the image, When clicking the No 1, will come popup, Then enter the records and add. it will display in the table such as No 3 & 4. But I want to group them according to the group. No 3 items are the same group No 4 is another group. But in here showing according to the inputs array.

In my controller I did,

```
public $i = -1;
public $inputs = [];
public $category_ids, $item_id, $group;

public function addLine($i)
    { 
        $i = $i + 1;
        $this->i = $i;
        array_push($this->inputs, $i);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want data in this format Group 1 - 38, Group 2 - 19

Comment: I want the group as item_id 18, and 20 because of both are belongs to Group 01 Then  item_id 19 belongs to Group 02. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a group items array by the following code. It will make a nested array of items for each group then you can use them by looping

```
$group = ['Group 01', 'Group 02', 'Group 01'];
$item_id = [18, 19, 20];
$group_items= [];
foreach($group as $key => $value) {
    $group_items[$value][] = $item_id[$key];
}
```

In your blade file

```
@foreach ($group_items as $group => $items)
   <tr> 
     <td class="p-2"> 
      {{ $group }} 
     </td>

     <td class="p-2"> 
     @foreach ($items as $item)
         {{ $item }}
     @endforeach
     </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```